# How to automate a series of actions in windows

Tags: batch-file, automation

I have a web application software which contains a textarea in the UI.I should paste the source code I have in the text area of that web application and click on the button submit. It processes the code and generate a pdf. I should click on the pdf and should specify the location to save it.

How to automate these series of actions for a number of code files?

I tried using batch files.I could open the application,copy a html content into another notepad file. But I can't figure out how to go to a speciofic option of the UI and click on it,etc.

Plz suggest me the way to do it using batch file or suggest any opensource tools to automate these functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of tools to achieve those kind of tasks - here are some suggestions which could help:

- [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/)
- [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)
- [WinMacro](http://senthilthecoder.com/software/winmacro/index.html)
- [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
- [Actions](http://app.jbbres.com/actions/)